# How to perform join and updates from two or more tables using SSIS ?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am working on an ETL task on SSIS. In this task I am trying to update a table 'Vendor' where I want to use an another table for some references and conditions in 'where' clause. Here is what I want to do -

```
ALTER TABLE Vendor ADD Imported BIT
Update  Vendor
SET     Imported = 1
-- (133 row(s) affected)

Update  Vendor
SET     Imported = 0
where   VendorName in (Select VendorName from MyDatabase..Vendor)

Update  l
SET     VendorName = t.VendorName,  -- Vendor name looks imported one has proper Capital letters in name, use the one from to-be-imported one
    Address1 = t.Address1,
    Address2 = t.Address2,
    City = t.City,
    State = t.State,
    Country = t.Country,
    PostalZip = t.PostalCode,
    Phone = t.NewPhone,
    Email = t.Email     
From    MyDatabase..Vendor l, Vendor t
where   l.VendorName = t.VendorName
and t.Imported = 0
-- (2 row(s) affected)
```

Please suggest me what should be the suitable procedure on SSIS package. I can use Execute SQL Task for the same but want to use an alternate approach as in Execute SQL Task I have to create a separate task for each SQL statement. 
Your precious replied will be welcomed.

Comment: I don't think you need a separate task for each SQL Statement. You can do it on the same Execute Sql Task.

Comment: Can you please explain how I can do this ?

Comment: add an Execute SQL Task on your control flow and paste your sql stament on SQLStament window. Also, do you really need to do the `alter table` everytime?

Comment: When I do this, I could not parse the query and it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a multi-statement Execute SQL Task like this, you have to end each separate statement with a semi-colon.   Do this, and it will work.

Comment: Okay I got this but do we have an alternate approach ?

Comment: You could put all these statements in a Stored Procedure, and call the stored procedure from an Execute SQL statement.